# Rails 3: Ruby 1.9.2: does it need /usr/bin/ruby1.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get the [Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl](http://railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) going. I spent a lot of time fighting various libraries. So I removed  all ruby software from my Ubuntu 10.4 system.

Then I installed Ruby 1.9.2.

```
 $ ruby -v
 ruby 1.9.2dev (2010-07-02) [i486-linux]
```

So far so good. Then I did

```
 sudo gem install rails
```

After a long time, it finished the installation. 
Then I ran

```
 $ rails -v
 bash: /usr/bin/rails: /usr/bin/ruby1.8: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

So...I have no /usr/bin/ruby1.8 on my system. How do I get Rails 3.0.3 to use my ruby at /usr/bin/ruby?

I appreciate any help you can give me.

Just to see if I could keep going, I tried

```
 $ cd /usr/bin
 $ sudo ln -s ruby1.9.2 ruby1.8
```

This let me keep going, but is it the right thing to do?

Comment: What's the output of `gem environment`?

Specifically the `RUBY VERSION` and `RUBY EXECUTABLE`.

Comment: "gem -v" yielded 1.3.7. "gem environment" yielded RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2010-07-02 patchlevel -1) [i486-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.9.2
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took trying 3 different methods of installing and uninstalling Ruby, but I finally got it!

I found a great tutorial by [Toran Billups](http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2010/09/01/How-to-install-Rails-3.0-and-Ruby-1.9.2-on-Ubuntu) which gives some great instructions. After analyzing what he did, it comes down to a few key concepts:

1. Some libraries that are independent of the Ruby version must be installed in the system (using "sudo apt-get").
2. Use RVM to install Ruby in your own account. i.e. no "sudo".
3. Use gem to install gems in your particular ruby environment. (i.e. no "sudo"). When you set 1.8 as the Ruby environment, the gems are installed in the RVM 1.8 tree in your environment. When you set 1.9.2 as the environment, gems are installed in the 1.9.2 tree in your environment.

Here, then, is the process.

1. Remove all Ruby programs (1.8.x and 1.9.2) and Ruby libraries from your Ubuntu 10.4 system.
2. Install RVM on your system, following the instructions at the <del>[RVM site](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/)</del>*(broken)* [RVM site](https://rvm.io/rvm/install).
3. Follow [Toran Billups' tutorial](http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2010/09/01/How-to-install-Rails-3.0-and-Ruby-1.9.2-on-Ubuntu), starting at the point where you install Ruby 1.8.7.
4. Follow the instructions at <del>[Michael Hartl's tutorial](http://railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)</del>*(broken)* [Michael Hartl's tutorial](http://rails-3-2.railstutorial.org/book/beginning) to get Rails 3.0 working with Ruby 1.9.2, github, heroku.com, rspec, spork, and autotest.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error after installing with RVM and opening new shells. The solution was to run:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.2 --default
```

P.S.
I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 and after two days of trial and error finally got rails 3 working with ruby 1.9.2. I highly recommend using RVM to install ruby a godsend!

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of it Bash is finding ruby1.8 when its running the `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` line from the rails script, even though it doesn't exist.  Try `/usr/bin/env which ruby` to see exactly what interpreter it's trying to load.

Comment: Before I did the ln -s /usr/bin/ruby1.9.2 /usr/bin/ruby1.8, there was no ruby1.8. Bash couldn't find it. But why would bash be looking for /usr/bin/ruby1.8 in the first place? I don't even have it installed on my system!

Comment: I'm not sure, the `bad interpreter` part of the error message is what makes me think it's the shebang line that it is erroring out on.  Opening up `bin/rails` from the rails gem folder it has `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` as its shebang so it should be using the first `ruby` found in your path to try and run it.  Somehow that's returning `/usr/bin/ruby1.8` to bash.  If you run `/usr/bin/env which ruby` it should list the full path to the interpreter it's finding.

Comment: Maybe open up `/usr/bin/rails` and check that is the first line in it.  It might have somehow been changed to `#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8` although I have no idea how that may have happened.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having a headache with this, and don't want to use RVM right now.

I saw that the shebang line for /usr/bin/gem was #!/usr/bin/ruby1.8 and that this was presumably the issue.

I made sure /etc/alternatives pointed to the correct gem script; this can be set with:

update-alternatives --config gem

Then I removed /usr/bin/gem and symlinked from /usr/bin/gem to /etc/alternatives/gem

It turns out the only difference in the gem scripts was the shebang line, so manually changing that would have worked too.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing back the version of my current Ruby (using RVM) to 2.0.x.

When i installed rails (two days ago) it was under the 2.0.0 version. Yesterday i changed to 2.1.x. Today i tried the rails command and got the error.

So turning back to the RVM Ruby version i installed rails did the trick.

Sorry by the bad english.

P.S. Using Ubuntu 13.10